# Eclipse/ZendStudio Snipplr plugin has no view

Tags: eclipse

I have installed the snipplr plugin on my ZendStudio 8. I can see the Snipplr4e section in Preferences and can even validate my API key but thats just about it.

Where do I actually access the snippets?